# AWS SNS delivery status

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am new in Aws, I am using Aws SNS to send notification, i am sending notifications to different topic not to endpoint. This is working perfectly.

When i `publish` notification, i got array like

```
object(Aws\Result)#84 (1) {
    ["data":"Aws\Result":private]=>
       array(2) {
         ["MessageId"]=>
         string(36) "************-7a29-591f-8765-************"
         ["@metadata"]=>
         array(4) {
         ["statusCode"]=>
         int(200)
         ["effectiveUri"]=>
        string(40) "https://sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
        ["headers"]=>
        array(4) {
            ["x-amzn-requestid"]=>
            string(36) "************-b737-5831-abf4-************"
            ["content-type"]=>
            string(8) "text/xml"
            ["content-length"]=>
            string(3) "294"
            ["date"]=>
            string(29) "Fri, 28 Oct 2016 08:59:05 GMT"
        }
        ["transferStats"]=>
            array(1) {
               ["http"]=>
               array(1) {
               [0]=>
               array(0) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using php at server side,
How can i get notification delivery status of all recepients by this `message id`?

Thanks in Anticipants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking how to obtain **notification delivery status** of messages sent via Amazon SNS.

The [Using Amazon SNS Topic Attributes for Message Delivery Status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/msg-status-topics.html) documentation says:

> Amazon SNS provides support to **log the delivery status of notification messages** sent to topics with the following Amazon SNS endpoints:
>
> - Application
> - HTTP
> - Lambda
> - SQS
>
> After you configure the message delivery status attributes, **log entries will be sent to CloudWatch Logs** for messages sent to a topic subscribed to an Amazon SNS endpoint.

I could not find a specific API call to request status by `message_id`. Instead, it appears that the logging information is sent to **CloudWatch Logs**. You would need to parse the logs to discover the status.

Comment: My endpoint is `Application` and i mentioned that log are generating, but how can i fetch delivery status of notification messages sent to topics by `message_id`? Is there some other way to find out?

Comment: Also can you tell me that is there any expiration duration/validity of logs at CloudWatch? Or it is available forever?

Comment: CloudWatch Logs are retained until specifically deleted. There is no method to fetch logs by `message_id` -- you would need to programmatically parse the logs via [getLogEvents()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-logs-2014-03-28.html#getlogevents) and find the information yourself.

Comment: hy John, How can i apply `Metric Filter` for generated logs via PHP? i think it will be useful for me, i will filter all logs by `message_id`(by Metric Filter),

Comment: A [CloudWatch Logs metric filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) will look for specific text within a log stored in CloudWatch logs, and will return matching lines. You would then need to parse these lines to extract information you seek. It's worth a try, but it would take some fudging.

Comment: okay, after a lot of research i checked a method `filterLogEvents`, in its parameter `filterPattern`(key) i passed my message_id like this `{ $.notification.messageId = "1********-a****-5***-9***-5***********" }`, and it is filtering my data according to my need, is it correct way to filter logs? If something is missing and it is benefitial for parsing logs, please suggest me.

Comment: When there will be a lot of log streams, may be this method `filterLogEvents` will take a lot of time, so how can i make filtering more accurate and fast? Also i think i save this logs in my DB, So after how much time i can store log info in DB? because i think Aws Sns try to resend notifications if failed in first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable 'Delivery status logging' to AWS Cloudwatch [More Info](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)
2. Adjust the user (used in script) to access the AWS Cloudwatch log
3. Read the log entry from cloudwatch with awssdk for php

See the sample code below

```html
require 'inc/awsSdkForPhp/aws-autoloader.php';
$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => '<YOUR KEY>',
        'secret' => '<YOUR SECRET>',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1', //  your aws from SNS region
    'version' => 'latest'
);
$cwClient = new \Aws\CloudWatchLogs\CloudWatchLogsClient($params);
$queryRes = $cwClient->startQuery([
  'endTime' => 1621231180,  // UNIX TIMESTAMP 
  'logGroupName' => 'sns/us-east-1/***/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber', // YOUR LOG GROUP NAME
  'queryString' => 'fields @timestamp, status, @message
  | filter notification.messageId="5a419afc-c4b3-55b3-85f9-c3e7676b2dd2"', // YOUR MESSAGE ID
  'startTime' => 1620954551 // START UNIX TIMESTAMP 
]);

$qryID = $queryRes->get('queryId');
sleep(3); // To wait the execution to be completed.
$resultObj =  $cwClient->getQueryResults(array(
  'queryId' => $qryID, // REQUIRED
));

//echo "<pre>";print_r($resultObj);echo "</pre>";
$result = $resultObj->get('results');

$jsnRs = json_decode($result[0][2]['value']); // TO get the delivery array 

echo "<br>status :".$jsnRs->status;
echo "<br>phone Carrier :".$jsnRs->delivery->phoneCarrier;
echo "<br>provider Response :".$jsnRs->delivery->providerResponse;
echo "<pre>";print_r($jsnRs);echo "</pre>";
```

I believe it will help someone