# Amazon SNS Service Push Notification delivered or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using Aws SNS to send notification, and sending notifications to different topics and is working perfectly.

When i `publish` notification, i got array like

```
object(Aws\Result)#84 (1) {
["data":"Aws\Result":private]=>
array(2) {
    ["MessageId"]=>
    string(36) "************-7a29-591f-8765-************"
    ["@metadata"]=>
    array(4) {
        ["statusCode"]=>
        int(200)
        ["effectiveUri"]=>
        string(40) "https://sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
        ["headers"]=>
    array(4) {
        ["x-amzn-requestid"]=>
        string(36) "************-b737-5831-abf4-************"
        ["content-type"]=>
        string(8) "text/xml"
        ["content-length"]=>
        string(3) "294"
        ["date"]=>
        string(29) "Fri, 28 Oct 2016 08:59:05 GMT"
    }
    ["transferStats"]=>
        array(1) {
            ["http"]=>
            array(1) {
            [0]=>
               array(0) {}
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I am using php at server side,

But i need to generate a report for each topic separately, that which endpoints (subscriber of topic) get notification and whether notifications are failed, and what is the percentage of successful delivery.

After a lot of research, i found that Aws CloudWatch can do my work, i also searched on stackOverflow for this, and got this answer:

[How to confirm delivery status when using amazonSNS mobile push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651315/how-to-confirm-delivery-status-when-using-amazonsns-mobile-push)

I also generated some log in CloudWatch,
By `describeLogGroups`, i am getting array like

```
[logGroups] => Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [logGroupName] => sns/ap-southeast-1/************/app/GCM/AndroidN
        [creationTime] => ************
        [retentionInDays] => 30
        [metricFilterCount] => 0
        [arn] => arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:************:log-group:sns/ap-southeast-1/************/app/GCM/AndroidN:*
        [storedBytes] => 3133
     )
 )
```

By `describeLogStreams`, i am getting array like

```
[logStreams] => Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [logStreamName] => 25
            [creationTime] => 1477574852344
            [firstEventTimestamp] => 1477574831966
            [lastEventTimestamp] => 1477574831966
            [lastIngestionTime] => 1477574852374
            [uploadSequenceToken] => ***********************8
            [arn] => arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:*********:log-group:sns/ap-southeast-1/**********/app/GCM/AndroidN:log-stream:25
            [storedBytes] => 627
        )
)
```

but confused that how to access it for a particular topic, because in my website i create some topics for group of users (endpoints), and now i want to show for every topic how much notification sent/failed to endpoints not to topic,

Thanks in Anticipants.

Comment: Just for reference... This question extends upon [AWS SNS delivery status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303673/aws-sns-delivery-status). However, this question asks something different, so is not a duplicate.

Comment: Both questions are asked by me, no duplicate,